# use yum in AWS private subnet EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc, aws-security-group

I'm trying to use yum in private subnet instance to using NAT Gateway

so my VPC settings is as follows.
[VPC Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvLV9.png)
I set my private subnet security group as follows
[Private Subnet Security Group Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wN80.png)
and I set my private subnet ACL as follows
[Private Subnet ACL Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDZzO.png)

I open TCP port in ACL but, I don't open any port in security group without ssh
However I can use yum in private subnet instances

I wonder why I can use yum in private subnet instances?

Answer (score 2):

The rules that you set for your security group are "inbound". The Linux command yum makes "outbound" connections. The "inbound" rules have no effect for "outbound" connections.

AWS Security Groups are "smart". This means that when a connection is made (inbound or outbound) the return port is automatically opened. Even if you have no ports open in your inbound security group, the outbound connection will still succeed.

Network ACLs are different. They are "dumb". This means that the inbound port must be open for an outbound connection. In your case you opened ports 1024 - 65535, which allows the outbound connection to succeed. If you close those ports, yum will stop working.

Note: ports below 1024 are reserved and require "privilege". For normal outbound connections the return port will be above 1024.

Comment: Really appreciate
It's helps me